# How can I use now() with Zend ->where

Tags: zend-framework

How can I use the now() in Zend? I searched everywhere but I just couldn't find the correct answer to my problem.

I need to get this to work but it just won't work.

```
->where('online <= now()');
```

I also tried

```
->$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   

->where('online <= $today')
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error is with the sql where statement - Please include the error so that we can asses the error correctly.

if the online field is a timestamp try,

```
->where('online <= ?', now());
```

or if the online field is a date time field try,

```
->$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   
->where('online <= ?', $today)
```

Essentially I have added the `?` that represents a parameter that the expression should expect.  This is then supplied by the variable.  Chaning the `'` to `"` will also work, but this method is better as it uses parameters rather than direct sql input.

More info on creating queries in the [zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html).

Comment: There is no PHP function `now()`, I think you mean the MySQL function, in which case it would be `->where('online <= ?', new Zend_DB_Expr('NOW()'));`